# How to find in a DLL which process loaded it?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I am refining a DLL module that acts as a sort of plugin for a Windows application.

This plugin is compatibile with various versions of a single software line. 
Now, for a certain functionality, I have to access the configuration files of the parent software. Since different versions of the software have these in different places, I have to find out which version loads the DLL.
The separate versions are readily discernable by the process executable name (i.e. abc_v1.exe, abc_v2.exe, abc_v3.exe).

Is there a way to get the name of the process that loaded the DLL? I am using C++ with some basic WinAPI commands, but not ATL, MFC or such.

Currently I am polling the parent software by use of it's own SDK functions, but that requires opening a connection. Depending on content of the configuration files, the DLL does not need to open a connection, so I would like to know which version loaded it before having to establish communication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) passing `NULL` as the module handle. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx):

> A handle to the loaded module whose path is being requested. If this parameter is NULL, GetModuleFileName retrieves the path of the executable file of the current process.